# Conditional statement in an SQL Function

Tags: db2

All I want is to how to include a conditional statement in a function.

For example, if I execute something like

```
select * from table(afunction(0));
select * from table(afunction(1));
```

Both statements will have different output.

I tried this,

```
create function afunction(custid int) 
returns table(customerid int) 
language sql 
reads sql data 
no external action 
deterministic 
return 
    if (custid = 0) then 
        select customerid from customer;
    else 
        select customerid from orderdone;
    end if;
```

But it resulted in an error.

I know I could just type out,

```
select customerid from customer;
select customerid from orderdone;
```

but my motive is to learn how to put a conditional statement in a function. I tried with 'case' but it doesn't work as well. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: For future reference, "doesn't work" isn't a problem description.  What results are you seeing?  Or not seeing?  Are you getting an error instead?  Which one?

Comment: sorry for confusion, i have edited my question. Thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a [compound statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html):

```
create function ...
begin
  if (custid = 0) then 
    return select customerid from customer;
  else 
    return select customerid from orderdone;
  end if;
end
```